# Calculating MSS and RSS in R

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis

I am trying to calculate the MSS and RSS using the output and the components of the regression model that I have created (model.1)

```
 model.1<-glm(wbw.df$x.percap ~ wbw.df$y.percap,family=gaussian)
```

Which part of the output do I need to be focusing on? For ex:

```
Call:
glm(formula = wbw.df$x.percap ~ wbw.df$y.percap, family = gaussian)

Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.061191  -0.006350  -0.005931  -0.003722   0.275066  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           0.006458   0.002766   2.334 0.021022 *  
wbw.df$totwlth.percap 0.030566   0.008933   3.422 0.000819 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.001005281)

    Null deviance: 0.15050  on 139  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.13873  on 138  degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
AIC: -565.06

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your goals for calculating MSS and RSS? Could you also explain why you're using a generalized linear model? What is the actual GLM that you want to fit? Why are you not using ordinary least squares, ie, with the function lm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand why you're fitting the model with `glm`. I suggest using ordinary least squares for model fitting:

```
lm(wbw.df$x.percap ~ wbw.df$y.percap)
```

You could then use the function `residuals`

```
residuals(lm(wow.df$x.percap ~ wbw.df$y.percap))
```

to get the vector of residuals. With it, square each and sum the result.

I hope that this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using glm, qpcR library can calculate the residual sum-of-squares of nls, lm, glm, drc or any other models from which residuals can be extacted. Here RSS(fit) function returns the RSS value of the model.

```
install.packages('qpcR')
library(qpcR)
model.1<-glm(wbw.df$x.percap ~ wbw.df$y.percap,family=gaussian)
RSS(model.1)
```

[check the link to see other functions of qpcR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qpcR/versions/1.4-1)